# TFS Repository deleting status after upgrading major version

Tags: tfs

In the past, we seem to have created a TFS repository that was not part of a project.  It seems that this is no longer supported by TFS in recent versions.

After updating TFS 2013 to 2015 and then 2017 we did not immediately notice the problem, but looking in the Collection Management screen on the web portal shows that the "Project" (which is not a project) is marked in a "Deleting" status.

[image: Deleting Status]
[image: Description Tooltip]

The [Microsoft page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3081117/after-team-foundation-server-2015-upgrade-administration-console-shows) about this says that if you want to keep the code, no action needs to be taken.  That "Deleting" status worries me however.

Is there any way to add an existing repo to a project?  I can create a new project.  I can add a new repo to a project.  Can I add an existing repo to a project?

Alternatively, can I "Un-Deleting" that repo somehow?

Answer (score 0):

That page have described this very clear:

> Otherwise, no action is required. **Placeholder team projects** are
>   hidden in Web Access and Team Explorer in Visual Studio. Therefore,
>   they have no significant effect on day-to-day usage. **As with any
>   other deleted item in Version Control**, you can still access the
>   corresponding project in Source Control Explorer if the **Show/Hide
>   Deleted Items** button is enabled.

As you said, Placeholder team projects are not real team projects. When you delete a real team project, it will permanently removes data associated with that project from the database. You cannot recover it later.

They are just as deleted folders/items in TFS, you could undelete them in Visual Studio Source Control. Just select the deleted folders and right click it select **undelete** , and check in pending changes. Then you could get/download all files in the repo to local. Create a new team project, add files to the project, finally delete the particular placeholder project.

[image]

Since there is no way to import deleted files to either a existing project or a new project. Above is a safety workaround, the only disadvantage is it will lose  the source control history of those folders. Otherwise, you could also take no action as the page suggested, the Placeholder team project will not be deleted. If you encounter any problem about this, you could contact the [TFS support](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-support/).

Comment: In source control explorer, the relevant repository and the files in it do not indicate that they are being deleted or marked for deletion.  The ONLY indication that anything is happening with that repository is in the Collection Management page of the Web portal.  The "Deleting" status there gives me pause because at some future date when we upgrade to a later version of TFS, I don't want to lose the repo as the installer decides to finalize the deletion.  I had hoped that I could retain all of the edit history, but it looks like I cannot.